# How to use local CocoaPods dependencies for Cordova Plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova, frameworks, cocoapods, podfile

I'm developing a Cordova plugin, and I need to add local pods to my project.

for distant pods we can add them in our plugin.xml file using an xml tag like this :

```
 <framework src="OpenSSL" type="podspec" spec="~> 1.0.0" />
```

Once we add this tag and we add our plugin to our cordova project, a **podfile**  containing this line **pod** **'OpenSSL' '~> 1.0.0'** will be automatically generated.

The question is how can we add a local pod to have in our podfile a line like this : **pod 'podName', path: '../myLocalPath'**

Answer (score 1):

In general, Cordova uses the `spec` field as whatever would normally come after the comma `,` in a Podfile. So all the options available [here in the Cocoapods docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod) should work – see "Using the files from a local path.".

```
<framework src="OpenSSL" type="podspec" spec=":path => '/Users/Jimmy/OpenSSL'" />
```

Another handy option is a direct (even private with SSH configured) git repo:

```
<framework src="OpenSSL" type="podspec" spec=":git => 'ssh://git@github.com/jimmy/OpenSSL.git'" />
```